# Detect exception in finally block

Tags: .net, exception

I'm trying to write a `Dispose` method which has the potentian to throw an exception.

The dispose is invoked in a `try-finally` pattern, via a `using` statement:

```
using(var widget = new Widget())
{
   widget.DoYourThing();
}
```

The problem is that if an exception is raised by the `Dispose` method, it replaces any exception which may have been raised during the body of the `using` block. Typically this exception is less-useful than the one thrown in the body.

What I would like is to write the `Dispose` method in such a way that it swallows its own exceptions if there is an exception already in progress. Something like the following would be ideal:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        this.Shutdown();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        this.Abort();

        // Rethrow the exception if there is not one already in progress.
        if(!Runtime.IsHandlingException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything which can provide this information?

Comment: There's a general problem here - if you're implementing the Dispose pattern, your Dipose method may be called on the finalizer thread. In turn, the rule for finalizers is that you *should not throw*. This tends to lead to the conclusion that Dispose methods shouldn't throw either.

Comment: "This tends to lead to the conclusion that Dispose methods shouldn't throw either" - avoid throwing if you can, of course, but some Dispose implementations need to throw.  For example, FileStream's Dispose method will attempt to flush any buffered data, and will throw if this flush fails.  Silently ignoring a failure to flush data is clearly not an option, so I'd conclude that in the general case, you must expect that a Dispose method can throw.

Comment: Currently, my `Dispose` implementation swallows all exceptions raised by inner methods like a good little implementation. It only causes problems, since the exceptions themselves are lost. I might just be inclined to write the exceptions to a diagnostic trace and keep the implementation as-is.

Comment: Additionally, the `Dispose(false)` path could be used to detect when code is being executed on the Finalizer thread and prevent any possible exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Is it truly necessary for your `Dispose` method to be able to throw an exception?

Perhaps you should create another disposal method with a different name, and have that throw an exception if necessary. Then implement `Dispose` by calling that other method, wrapped in a `try` block that will swallow the exception so that `Dispose` never throws.

Comment: I hope you can see from my example that `Shutdown` is exactly the method you describe. My current implementation does swallow all exceptions raised by this method, but some of them are valuable.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: So, the lesson is "don't use a disposable object in a `using` statement if the `Dispose` call may throw an exception" or "don't write `Dispose` methods which can throw exceptions"? Perhaps both?